# How to print on the same line, using one-line if else in python

Tags: python

to print on same line we use

```
for i in range(10):
    print i,  # python 2
    print (i,end='') # python 3
```

but how to do it inside one line `if - else`

```
for i in range(10):
    print((i,end=' ') if (i%2==0) else (i))
```

it gives the following error:

```
 print((i,end=' ') if (i%2==0) else (i)))
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is your desired outcome? `0 2 4 6 8`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end=('\n' if i % 2 else ' '))
```

No need for the `==` if you reverse the logic.

For a true one-liner consider this less readable code:

```
print(*('{}{}'.format(i, '\n' if i%2 else ' ') for i in range(10)), sep='', end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is "one line" even interesting? Are we playing Code Golf?

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, '' if i % 2 == 0 else '\n', end='')
```

Answer (score -1):

I am at python 3. This works:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end=' ') if(i%2==0) else (i)
```

Comment: This may work, but it looks rather unpythonic to me.

Comment: @TimPietzcker TS does not ask what pythonic and what is not pythonic. He/she is asking how to code it in 1 line using python. And describing a code to be pythonic or not sounds somewhat subjective. Are you voting down due to subjectivity?

Comment: I didn’t downvote. Using a side effect is unpythonic according to the Zen of Python (“explicit is better”).  If someone asks you how to hammer in a screw, shouldn’t you rather tell them to use a screwdriver instead of giving hammer recommendations?

Comment: I got your point but TS is asking about hammering a screw because he keeps hammering at the wrong direction ie. the error. He didn't specifically ask how to do it better since he already knows how to hammer a screw. Just my opinion on this matter :).

Answer (score -1):

Possible one-liner

```
''.join([' ' if i % 2 else str(i) for i in range(10)])
```

Comment: What makes it worth -1?